# How to return right value in python class

Tags: python

I have a problem with this piece of code not running properly.

This is the ArrayList with all the functions

```
class ArrayList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.inArray = [2,3,4,5]
        self.count = 0

    def get(self, i):
        return self.inArray[i]

    def set(self, i, e):
        self.inArray[i] = e

    def length(self):
        return self.count

    def append(self, e):
        self.inArray[self.count] = e
        self.count += 1
        if len(self.inArray) == self.count:
            self._resizeUp()     # resize array if reached capacity

    def insert(self, i, e):
        for j in range(self.count,i,-1):
            self.inArray[j] = self.inArray[j-1]
        self.inArray[i] = e
        self.count += 1
        if len(self.inArray) == self.count:
            self._resizeUp()     # resize array if reached capacity

    def remove(self, i):
        self.count -= 1
        val = self.inArray[i]
        for j in range(i,self.count):
            self.inArray[j] = self.inArray[j+1]
        return val

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.inArray[:self.count])

    def _resizeUp(self):
        newArray = [0 for i in range(2*len(self.inArray))]
        for j in range(len(self.inArray)):
            newArray[j] = self.inArray[j]
        self.inArray = newArray

    #ex1
    def appendAll(self, A):

        for i in range(len(A)):
            self.inArray.append(A[i])

    #ex2
```

```
def removeVal(self, e):
        for i in range (self.count):
            if self.inArray[i] == e:
                return True
        return False
```

I've got this code which should return true if my ArrayList contains e, however in testing it doesnt work.

```
ls = ArrayList()
print(ls.inArray)
ls.appendAll([42,24])
print(ls.inArray)
```

ls.inArray returns (2,3,4,5,42,24). However when I run  the test `ls.removeVal(4)` the output returns False.

The number 4 is clearly ls.inArray and should return true instead

Comment: where is `ArrayList` defined?

Comment: I have edited the post to give context, sorry about that

Comment: how about changing it to just `return e in self.inArray`

Comment: You use ``for i in range (self.count)`` but your ``self.count == 0``.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
remove(self, i)
```

`i` is an index not an element in the array. So the fact that 4 is in the array has nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def __init__(self):
>     self.inArray = [2,3,4,5]
>     self.count = 4  # your code: self.count = 0
> ```
>
> self.count initial value should be 4,because initial  **len(self.inArray)** is 4.in addition,the function **removeal** should like this

```
    def removeVal(self, e):
    print(self.count,self.inArray)
    for i in range(self.count):
        print(self.inArray[i])
        if self.inArray[i] == e:
            return True
    return False
```